# How to change background size of the menu on mouseover in HTML

Tags: html, css

This is my problem... I had my mouseover background effect... but i really want to know how to change the background size.. coz i tried everything i know (few because im a newbie in HTML)

This is my CSS :

```
ul#menu li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline;
}
```

On stylesheet:

```
li a {
background: url(rectangle.png) left top no-repeat;

}

li a:hover {
background: url(rectangle.png) left top no-repeat ;

}
```

The List:

```
<ul id="menu" style="float: left;margin-left:-50;position: fixed;top: 20px;
    left: 445px;">
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">HOME </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">OUR WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: what is a "background size" ? you mean the size of the background image?

Comment: Add a `#menu li:hover` selector and add a `background-size` property. Add the required value.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `#menu li:hover` selector and add a `background-size` property. Add the required value.

```css
li a {
background: url(http://www.rehotechnologies.com/images/Back.jpg) left top no-repeat;

}

li a:hover {
background-size: 50% 50%; /*add desired value*/
}
ul#menu li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu" style="float: left;margin-left:-50;position: fixed;top: 20px;
    left: 445px;">
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">HOME </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">OUR WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's so helpful. thanks. is there any chance that i can make the background larger than the menu text? because it only covers the menu text :)

Comment: Thanks. im practicing html code and i really need some help from pros like you :) i need somethink like this site's menu http://corneredgeinteractive.com/ but that's already a js code. maybe there's a substitude by using css

Comment: Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/db1y1fc4/. Here, I used an image of arrow as the background. On hover, it centers inside the `li`

Comment: If you are not designing a fixed width website, then please don't use fixed positioning on `ul`. Use `margin: 0 auto;` and define a width of the `ul` and change its `display` property to `block` : http://jsfiddle.net/24d1o7w3/

Comment: cool. but i made the height higher but the extra space appears in the bottom. how can i customize the image so that it has no margin on on top?

Comment: im practicing. and im using the website above as my design. i can't put the menu on top with the logo if there's no fixed positioning. i dont know how :/

Comment: Actually `background-image` don't have margins. You have to set `background-position` for images. 

`background-image: x% y%;` x% is the horizontal offset, and y% is the vertical offset. Adjust this to position the image. :)

Comment: How can i adjust the image to become more at top, less on bottom and center on horizontal? i dont know how to use positioning :O

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is to fit the background changed on hover.

try adding

`background-size:cover;`

in

```
li a:hover {
 background: url(rectangle.png) left top no-repeat ;
}
```